# Is there a way in C++ to define an enum such that its values must be fully qualified when accessed?

Tags: c++, enums

One of the things that most bothers me about C++ enums is the fact that enum values can be accessed without any context to give the reader an indication of which type is being accessed.  In other words, if I have:

typedef enum Color { NONE, RED, GREEN, ... };

I can compare variables against "NONE", for example, without the need to write "Color::NONE".  Is there a way to define an enum type in such a way as to require that the value be fully qualified?  This is what C# does, for example.

Comment: Yes, but only part of the language (not a library solution) as of C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the new `enum class`, but the semantics aren't the same.  It's strictly part of C++ 11/14 as well.

`enum class type { t1, t2, t3 };`

Comment: I will have to side with this answer. That is what I use.

Comment: What do you mean by "the semantics aren't the same"?  Defining them is a little different, but using them seems to be exactly what I want.  Thank you!

Comment: You can't use them interchangeably with integers since they're no longer implicitly converted.  So, it's not backwards compatible.  Also, since an `enum class` isn't the same as a different `enum class` in regard to type, it can do things you might not expect.

Answer (score 3):

Put your enum inside a namespace with the name you want to qualify them with.

```
namespace Color{
  typedef enum thisNameDoesntMatter {NONE, RED, GREEN, ...};
}
```

Comment: I considered this, and it seems like a little bit of a trick, but the results seem worth it to me.  So, thank you!

Comment: As a bonus, you can put functions like parse(), toString(), getAll() etc. in the same namespace.

Comment: @vargonian: I would say that anything you do is going to be "a bit of a trick" as the language allows me to type `NONE` (and that is the canonical way to do it).  IMO I would not do something like this.  Those of us who know C++ would find it strange.

Comment: The main problem with this is that you can't have a variable of type `Color`.